# How to get the last byte item from a bytes list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a bytes list and want to get the last item, while preserving its bytes type. Using [-1] it gives out an int type, so this is not a direct solution.

Example code:

```
x = b'\x41\x42\x43'
y = x[-1]
print (y, type(y))
# outputs:
67 <class 'int'>
```

For an arbitrary index I know how to do it:

```
x = b'\x41\x42\x43'
i = 2 # assume here a valid index in reference to list length
y = x[i:i+1]
print (y, type(y))
# outputs:
b'C' <class 'bytes'>
```

Probably I can calculate the list length and then point an absolute length-1 number, rather than relative to list end.

However, is there a more elegant way to do this ? (i.e. similar to the simple [-1]) I also cannot imagine how to adapt the [i:i+1] principle in reverse from list end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways I think the one you're interested in is:

```
someBytes[-1:]
```

Edit: I just randomly decided to elaborate a bit on what is going on and why this works. A bytes object is an immutable arbitrary memory buffer so a single element of a bytes object is a byte, which is best represented by an int. This is why someBytes[-1] will be the last int in the buffer. It can be counterintuitive when you're using a bytes object like a string for whatever reason (pattern matching, handling ascii data and not bothering to convert to a string,) because a string in python (or a str to be pedantic,) represents the idea of textual data and isn't tied to any particular binary encoding (though it defaults to UTF-8). So the last element of "hello" is "o" which is a string since python has no single char type, just strings of length 1. So if you're treating a bytes object like a memory buffer you likely want an int but if you're treating it like a string you want a bytes object of length 1. So this line tells python to return a slice of the bytes object from the last element to the end of the bytes object which results in a slice length one containing only the last value in the bytes object and a slice of a bytes object is a bytes object.

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially cast that int back to a `bytes` object:

```
>>> z = bytes([y])
>>> z == b'C'
True
```

...in the event that you can't easily get around fetching the values as ints, say because another function you don't have control of returns them that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
x = b'\x41\x42\x43'
```

Then you will get:

```
>>> x
b'ABC'
```

As you said, x[-1] will give you Ord() value.

```
>>> x[-1]
67
```

However, if you want to get the value of this, you can give:

```
>>> x.decode()[-1]
'C'
```

If you do want to get the value 43, then you can give it as follows:

```
>>> "{0:x}".format(x[-1])
'43'
```

Comment: For pure ASCII that would be fine, but I rather prefer to avoid encode/decode processing (if possible) when individual bytes are plausible to be at random in range 0x00-0xff (even if explicit 'Latin-1' encoding is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Example above

```
>>> z = bytes([y])
>>> z == b'C'
True
```

Same you can get with

```
x.strip()[-1:]
```

Output

```
b'C'
```

So,

```
bytes(b'\x41\x42\x43')
```

Give

```
b'ABC'
```